# Patch or modify "require()" in Node for worker threads

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I have a potentially odd use case for patching, or modifying Node's `require()` function. I have the following, which works great for single threaded (or non worker) applications:

```js
const Module = require('module');
const originalRequire = Module.prototype.require;

Module.prototype.require = function () {
 // do stuff

 return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

However, the third party code I need to "adjust" (not in my control), makes use of worker threads that also use `require()`.

Is there a way I can modify the global `require()` function that would also take affect when used in a worker thread?

All I need to do is modify the path for certain files that are imported this way, which is easily done via `Array.prototype.replace`.

I've been scratching around on this for some time, so any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not the cleanest solution (but then again, neither is overwriting `require`), you can overwrite `require('worker_threads').Worker`:

```js
const wt = require('worker_threads');
const _Worker = wt.Worker;
wt.Worker = function(...args) {
    console.log('Creating a worker!');
    return new _Worker(...args);
}
```

You could either use the constructor's [options](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_new_worker_filename_options) to add `['-r', '/some/module/path']`*([won't work for ES6 modules](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module))* to `execArgv`, causing the Worker thread to immediately require a module, or alternatively replace the "entry point" of the Worker thread to point at your own code/script, do your changes and then start the original entrypoint.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll give this a go sometime today!